# How do I determine if a USB 3.1 port is 5 or 10 gbps?

Tags: linux-mint, usb, hardware

The physical ports are labeled `3.1` and `lsusb -v` shows `bcdUSB 3.1`. But there's two versions of 3.1, one that is 5gbps and one that is 10gbps. Is there a command to see if I have the ones that run at 10gbps or only the 5gbps ports?

How do I determine if a USB 3.1 port is 5 or 10 gbps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the USB speed from:

```
cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/usb4/speed
5000
```

This will give you the bus speed in `Mbps`.

OR

```
lsusb -t
  Bus 04.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 5000M
  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
```

Comment: `lsusb -t` is a lot easier to remember. Looks like mine are `10000M`.